# Check/uncheck all checkboxes in array when one is checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript

I am working on a marketing preference form, and I'd like the checkbox at the top to toggle all checkboxes in the row for 'partner publications' and all checkboxes in both rows for 'this publication' (these are opt-outs). There are multiple sections of publications, each with its own check-all, so this checkbox should only check all in this section.

I've already got thisPub and partnerPub bound together with the following code:

```
var chk344 = $('#optd344');
var chk343 = $('#optd343');

chk343.on('click', function(){
  if( chk343.is(':checked') ) {
    chk344.attr('checked', true);
    }
});

chk502.on('click', function(){
  if( chk502.not(':checked') ) {
    chk501.attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

and here is what I've got so far on the checkAll behavior, but it is not doing anything:

```
var chkAllEventsLegal = $('#events-legal-checkthis');
var allEventsLegal = $('#optd343', '#optd344');

chkAllEventsLegal.on('click', function(){
  if( chkAllEventsLegal.not(':checked') ) {
    allEventsLegal.attr('checked', false);
    }
});

chkAllEventsLegal.on('click', function(){
  if( chkAllEventsLegal.is(':checked') ) {
    allEventsLegal.attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Note that I cannot edit all of the html directly (to add classes or whatnot). It would have to be done through JS.

```
<div class="subsection-wrapper" id="events-legal-wrapper">
  <div id="eventslegaldonot">I do not wish to receive marketing messages from:</div>
  <div id="eventslegalthispub">This Publication</div>
  <div id="eventslegalpartners">Partners of This Publication</div>
  <hr class="sectionend">
  <span class="subcat-label events-legal">All ALM Legal Events Publications</span>
  <div id="events-legal-checkthis-wrapper"><input class="checkall" id="events-legal-checkthis" type="checkbox"><span class="optoutcheck"></span></div>
  <div id="events-legal-checkpartner-wrapper"><input class="checkall" id="events-legal-checkpartner" type="checkbox"><span class="optoutcheck"></span></div>
  <hr class="sectionend">
  <span class="subcat-label events-legal">ALM Experts Events</span>
  <div id="pd343"><input name="opt10935" value="N" id="optd343" [-checkedopt10935-]="" type="checkbox"><span class="optoutcheck"></span><span class="questionlabel ">ALM Experts Events&nbsp;</span><div id="longd343" class="longdescopt" style="display:none"></div></div>
  <div id="pd344"><input name="opt10936" value="N" id="optd344" [-checkedopt10936-]="" type="checkbox"><span class="optoutcheck"></span><span class="questionlabel ">ALM Experts Events Partner&nbsp;</span><div id="longd344" class="longdescopt" style="display:none"></div></div>
```

Comment: It would help to see an example HTML snippet. You're using jQuery, so you should be able to construct a selector that finds all the right checkboxes....

Comment: I've added that above. They continue in the same manner, but some input id's are skipped (i.e. optd343 and optd344 are grouped, optd345 and optd346 may be skipped).

Comment: Here, try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kdfv6qhL/1/  Some small changes to the jquery code. Assumes jquery 3.2.1

Comment: Yes, but it works in the fiddle ... so if it doesn't work on the actual page, then you have something different than what you reported above. So you should update the question to reflect the problem or debug what the difference is. For example, I don't see a `#hideother` or `#other` in the DOM, but you reference them in `checkOtherFillinCheckbox`.